# What am I doing wrong in this Monogame class?

Tags: c#, monogame

What am I doing wrong in this class? I'm using monogame and C# but my object won't render in the program.

```
class Player : Game
    {
        Texture2D PlayerSprite;
        Vector2 PlayerPosition;


        public Player()
        {
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            PlayerSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("spr_Player");
            PlayerPosition = Vector2.Zero;
        }

        public void Update()
        {


        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch SpriteBatch)
        {
            SpriteBatch.Begin();
            SpriteBatch.Draw(PlayerSprite,PlayerPosition, new Rectangle(0, 0, 32,32), Color.White);
            SpriteBatch.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: No error, it just isn't display my object when I compile. That's in another class called player should I be referencing something else from the Game1 class?

Comment: @Liam Earle, where are you creating a Player?

Comment: It's impossible to say what the problem is from the code you've posted. One thing that looks particularly odd is that it's a `Player` deriving from the `Game` class.

Comment: Is the Player the game class? (the starting point) Or is it another object your game class calls to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The Load, Update, and Draw methods belong to the inherited Game class and are overrided by it.
- You too need to start your SpriteBacth object.
- GraphicsDevice object has exist in Game main class.

Try this:

```
class Player : Game
{
    Texture2D PlayerSprite;
    Vector2 PlayerPosition;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public Player()
    {
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        PlayerSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("spr_Player");
        PlayerPosition = Vector2.Zero;
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(PlayerSprite,PlayerPosition, new Rectangle(0, 0, 32,32), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
```